# I am using Tinkerpop 3 and Gremlin. Can someone tell how I can commit the graph that I create using TinkerGraph.open()?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am using Tinkerpop3 and Gremlin console (by running gremlin.bat). After I create a graph, add nodes, edges to it, if for some reason the console has to be closed I cannot retrieve the graph I created previously. Could someone please tell how I can save the graph I create ?
example- `graph = TinkerGraph.open()`
// commands to add nodes and edges 
// Committing this graph to the db

Answer (score 3):

There is no `commit()` for TinkerGraph as it's not transactional, but you can save your graph in several different formats. Check out [Gremlin I/O](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_gremlin_i_o) docs to learn about the supported formats and get some examples on how to save / load graphs.